# Java: best way to find and remove an element from linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I've been wondering about this for quite some time and haven't found a good answer to that yet on SO.

What I want to do is to find an element in a linked list and delete it immediately. If I constructed the linked list on my own, it would be easy, since Ijust traverse the doubly linked list:

```
-> N1 <-> N2 <-> N3 <-> N4 <-> N5 <-
```

and when you find e.g. N3, you change the node.previous and node.next pointers such that:

```
-> N1 <-> N2 <-> N4 <-> N5 <-
```

If the element in in the middle, this would require roughly n/2 steps.

Is there a proper approach to do this in [`java.util.LinkedList<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)?

An approach that is insufficient for me is:

```
Integer found = null;
for(Integer elem : list){
    if(hasCertainProperty(elem)){
        found = elem;
    } 
}
if(found != null){
    list.remove(found);
}
```

If the element is the middle element in the list (double linked list, so search from end of the list is theoretically possible if index is known) it would require a maximum of roughly n/2 + n/2 = n steps. Whereas in the self-made traverse it would only need n/2 steps.

I know those 2 and other approaches are in O(n), but you know, sometimes that n/2 makes a difference in practice.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need that loop? Just call remove(Object).

Comment: The `java.util.LinkedList` does just that: https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/util/linkedlist.java#L-358

Comment: This is for simplification. Imagine it's a more complicated object and I only want to compare a certain property

Comment: I can't use remove, since I have to find the object to remove by a more complex comparison. I updated the question, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: @AndiR in that case, a Map would be a better data structure to use.

Comment: @Eran good input. But there are certain advantages to doubly-linked-lists that I don't want to sacrifice. I would be really interested in how to doing this properly.

Comment: @AndiR The proper way to deal with `LinkedList` by using its properties is to use a `ListIterator` which you obtain by using `list.listIterator(startIndex)`. You then step through the list using the iterator and call `iter.remove()` once found, which will remove the last element returned by the iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 will do this for you.

```
list.removeIf(x -> hasCertainProperty(x));
```

This internally loops through the list, checks for each item `x` whether it satisfies your condition `hasCertainProperty`, and removes the item. I guess you should not be concerned about the performance. Java will handle it for you.

Apart from that, you should use `ListIterator` which was exactly made for that purpose. You obtain it by using [LinkedList#listIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int)):

```
ListIterator<Integer> listIter = list.listIterator(0);
while (listIter.hasNext()) {
    Integer element = listIter.next();

    if (hasCertainProperty(element)) {
        listIter.remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

Its `remove` does not need any lookup, since it maintains a pointer to the node while iterating. So it has hands on the node you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Just for curiosity: Is there any solution for this before Java 8?

Comment: @AndiR Yes, the same way `removeIf` works internally. By using a `ListIterator`. Thats also the *correct* way to deal with `LinkedList` if you want to use its properties and avoid the second lookup for removal.